# Control router from Internet side

Tags: dd-wrt

Sometimes I need to administrate my DDWRT router when I'm not at home. For this reason I'm planning to enable router web interface from Internet side. How risky is it? Can I somehow reduce risks? I do this with my another Asus router with Asus original router program and it works fine.
What are other options to control router when I'm not at home?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1788665/access-router-from-internet It's still not a smart idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do it that way.

Setup a VPN and remote desktop.

Connect the VPN

Then use a remote desktop product to connect to a PC.

Then use that PC to configure your router.

You could even use a raspberry Pi or similar, as Pi's as in short supply.

Setup port forwarding in the router to forward the VPN port to a raspberry Pi or etc.

Answer (score 1):

> How risky is it?

Considering the past history of various home routers having vulnerabilities (or even deliberate backdoors) that allow accessing their remote control without proper authentication, I would go with "very risky".

> Can I somehow reduce risks?

Do not expose anything except software that is widely trusted to not have security issues. For example, VPN servers (such as WireGuard or OpenVPN) usually have far fewer moving parts and far fewer potential security risks than a router's web-management interface that was quickly thrown together.

> I do this with my another Asus router with Asus original router program and it works fine.

"Working fine" is **not mutually exclusive** with "doing more than it should". *Most* vulnerable services appear to work perfectly fine when used in the normal way; what matters is how they handle the requests you *don't* normally issue.